# When extending Obect.prototype and then using for in on a istance, js iterate through prototype too

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I add this method to the object prototype:

```
if( !Object.prototype.forEach ) {
    Object.prototype.add({
       'forEach': function(fn) {
            var object = this, ret;

            Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
                if (ret === false)
                    return;

                ret = fn.call(null, object[key], key, object);
            });

            return object;
        }
    });
}
```

then do this:

```
 switch( typeOf( arguments[0] ) ) {
     case 'string':
         // ...

     case 'object':
         var prop;
         for(prop in arguments[0]) {
             // ...
         }
```

And the code iterates through `forEach` too. 
if `arguments[0]` is `{a: 'a', b: 'b'}`, it iterates through `a,b,forEach`.
How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is `Object.prototype.add()` defined? If you wrote that yourself, you need to make sure that the keys that are added are non-enumerable using `Object.defineProperty()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very bad idea ever to add to `Object.prototype`. The opportunity for conflicts is just too great. You could use a lib that happens to use the property name you added as a marker, doing one thing if it's present on a given object but something else if it isn't. (ES2015 actually had to add a whole new kind of property name [`Symbol`] in order for built-in operations to have logic like that [e.g., for getting iterators and similar].)

But if you do it anyway, ensure that the property you add is *non-enumerable* by using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "forEach", {
    value: function() { /*...*/ },
    enumerable: false // This is actually the default, just here for emphasis
});
```

I'd suggest that wherever you got that `Object.prototype.add` function is probably not a place to learn from.